# Converting byte array format from parquet file to list of floats using tensorflow data

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, parquet

I am trying to setup a data pipeline, that reads data from parquet files, then convert proper format(byte array to list of floats), after that it will be fed to tensorflow fit method.

Note: My actual input data is too huge, so reading it in batches for training.

Got an issue in setting up the input data pipeline

Below is the sample code, with the kind of input I've got.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_io as tfio

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'col1':['[1.2, 2.3, 4.5]', '[1.0, 2.2, 4.3]'], 'col2':['[1.2, 0.3, 0.9]', '[1.1, 9.2, 5.3]']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'col1':['[1.1, 2.1, 4.1]', '[1.09 2.29, 4.39]'], 'col2':['[12.2, 20.3, 20.96]', '[12.1, 19.2, 15.3]']})

df1.to_parquet("foo.parquet")
df2.to_parquet("bar.parquet")

columns = {
    "col1": tf.TensorSpec(tf.TensorShape([]), tf.string), 
    "col2": tf.TensorSpec(tf.TensorShape([]), tf.string),
}

ds = tf.data.Dataset.list_files("*.parquet")
ds = ds.interleave(lambda f: tfio.IODataset.from_parquet(f, columns=columns), cycle_length=2, block_length=2) # returns an ordered dict

def decode_json(ip):
    return tf.py_function(json.loads, [ip], Tout=[tf.float32])

def decode(ip):
    out1 = ip["col1"].map(decode_json)
    out2 = ip["col2"].map(decode_json)
    return out1, out2

ds = ds.map(decode)

for elem in ds:
    print(elem)
```

**This gives error "AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'map'"**

Answer (score 0):

> This gives error "AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'map'"

It would help if you told us on which line.

I'm pretty sure it's this line.

```
out1 = ip["col1"].map(decode_json)
```

I think `tfio.IODataset.from_parquet(f, columns=columns)` returns a dataset of dictionaries of tensors.

The `ds.map(decode)` line applies decode to each item in the dataset. The items are dictionaries of tensors.

I think what you want is:

```
def decode(ip):
    out1 = decode_json(ip["col1"])
    out2 = decode_json(ip["col2"])
    return out1, out2
```